# Solve Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_AES'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pycrypto, zappa

I am trying to deploy my lambda function that makes a requests and decrypts data using pycrypto's module Crypto.Cipher AES. This is how my import looks:

```
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import gzip
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import base64
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import time
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

I run my code in my local Mac Environment and it works perfectly, but when I upload my package to AWS Lambda and test it, I get the following error:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_AES'
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734744/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function) question and downloaded the pycrypto package from this git repo, made the build and copied the results to my lambda folder, packaged it and still didn't work.

I checked the result of the build and I noticed that within this folder:

```
pycrypto-2.6.1/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
```

The AES files are generated with an extension related to my Mac OS

[image: Mac Cipher files]

I tried building the package on a Linux EC2 instance, but still get the same error (although the files change)

[image: Linux Cipher Files]

I tried a new path based on the following question but still failed with the exact same error.

["errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984720/errormessage-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function)

Why is AWS Lambda not able to read the AES module in the pycrypto package? I have deployed Lambda function with other external libraries and never faced this issue.

Comment: This worked for me now using python2:

https://github.com/Doerge/awslambda-pycrypto

I see that the _AES.cpython-27m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so module in this complied package lacks all of that extension and is just named _AES.so.

Can someone explain why compiling it by myself results in this format and-or the wrong format? Will leave it open for a while as I am interested in understanding why compiling this package for AWS lambda is such troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me now **using python2**:

https://www.github.com/Doerge/awslambda-pycrypto

I just downloaded this project and zipped my `lambda_function.py` file with both the `Crypto` and `pycrypto-2.6.1.dist-info` folders.

I see that the compiled `.so` files in `Crypto/Cipher/` (like `_AES.so`) lack the python version and OS architecture and distribution that mine had (i.e: `AES.cpython-27m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`). I will update my answer if I find a way to build the package properly by myself rather than using a third person compiled library.